# Export table to another access database

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a query in my Access database and a table with absolutely the same structure in another Access database.
I'm need to write a script which adds all entries from the query to the table. How can I do this?

The difference between my task and functionality of `Extarnal Data -> Export -> Access Database` is that I need to **add** new entries and save the old, but this tool can only **replace**  old entries to new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a linked table in the source database, to the destination table.
2. Then, use an append query to insert the results from your query into the linked table.

Edit: You can also do this with a single SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable (Field1, Field2)
IN "C:\path\to\file.accdb"
SELECT Field1,Field2
FROM SourceTable
```

But [the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177907%28v=office.12%29.aspx) says:

> For improved performance and ease of use, use a linked table instead of IN.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to link the table in VBA...

```
strDbName = "C:\FolderPath\DatabaseName.mdb"
strLinkTbl = "tblNameOfTableYouWantToLink"
strNameTbl = "tblWhatYouWantToNameIt" ' This can be the actual 
                                      ' table name or something different

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", strDbName, _
    acTable, strLinkTbl, strNameTbl
```

Then your SQL looks like:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO " & strNameTbl _
   & " (Field1, Field) SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM SourceTable
```